# How to create a ring (round) ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I need to set a round shape on top of an ImageView

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
float[] outerR = new float[]{8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
 RoundRectShape roundrect = new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null);
 ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundrect);
```

This provides an oval shape. I need a round shape. How to fix this? Thx

[image]

Comment: Could you please add expected output image.

Comment: I did add the output of the round circle. Right now it's an oval one.

Comment: This you can achieve using Framelayout or RelativeLayout. Inside any of the layout just add Image and textview. Play around with gravity for FrameLayout and alignParentEnd for RelativeLayout.

Comment: Isn't there a way I can use RoundRectShape to create a round button instead of an oval one? The shape is done using the ShapeDrawable class. I don t understand where to use the framelayout and relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

First create a `xml drawable` file into your `drawable` folder into the `res` directory.
Then into that `xml` file paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

and set this `drawable` as the `background` of your `textView`. Yeah, that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing this way.

```
     <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**bg_circle**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <size android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

By this you will get the same output.

Comment: and with the ShapeDrawable can I do the same?

Comment: I have not used ShapeDrawable. May be you can.